# jQuery selector for links to images which tolerates query strings

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors, hyperlink, query-string

I'm looking for a jQuery selector to find all links to images, which is simple enough with say,

`$('a[href$="jpg"], a[href$="jpeg"], a[href$="png"], a[href$="gif"]')`

But this breaks if my link has a query string appended to it, like this:

`<a href="http://example.com/image1.jpg?1737892">link</a>`

Is there a way to select all image links like the above, but which will still work if the image link has a query string at the end of it?

Comment: You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and implement that logic.

Comment: Sorry, @FelixKling, not following, can you explain? Doesn't filter still require me to have a selector which recognizes a link to an image but doesn't balk at a query string appended to the url?

Comment: The idea was to select all links and use `filter` to perform some more complex computation on the links, such as using regular expressions. Selectors are quite limited, `filter` lets you implement any logic to restrict the set of selected elements.

Comment: Fair enough. Does anyone have an example of a regex in javascript that would catch image links regardless of query string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this breaks is because the `$` part of the selector means it's only looking for `jpg` at the end of the `href`. Use the contains selector (`*`) instead, and include the dot of the extension:

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"], a[href*="jpeg"], a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"]')
```

Note though, that this means it would match the following urls too:

```
http://mysite.com/fakelink.jpg.aspx
http://mysite.com/page.php?param=image.jpg
```

So you're not 100% guaranteed to be selecting a link to an image, even though this eventuality is unlikely.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2MRP)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I could also do something like:  `$(a[href$='.jpg'], a[href*='.jpg?], etc)'`  right? Would I need to escape the question mark?

Answer (score 4):

you could add the `.` to the expression, as in ".jpg" and then use `*=`

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"], a[href*=".jpeg"]')
```

Comment: @j08691, please also explain why, or show better solution. thanks.

Comment: @j08691 this will work fine for images with querystrings: http://jsfiddle.net/u2MRP/